# displaying data in django template using detail view

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i'm having a problem displaying data on DetailView Template , basically  wanna display all the data of one project areas and tasks my models looks like that

```
##models    
class Project(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        ...


    class Area(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        project = models.ForeignKey(Project ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name='areas' )

    class Task(models.Model):
        ....
        area = models.ForeignKey(Area ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name='tasks' )

#view 
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project-detail.html'
```

#### this finaly worked in template

```
{% for area in object.areas.all %}
    {{area}}<br />
    {% for t in area.tasks.all %}
     {{ t }}<br />
     {% endfor %}
     <hr/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You haven't shown what you tried. If you can show areas, you should be able to show tasks. Post your template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  thanks after taking a break and checking it out with a clear head i've seen the problem in my template . what i wanna know is  looping inside the template the only solution to that  !?iis it possible to add extra context in a form of Queryset filtring via instance ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) and modify Detail like this:

```
#view 
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project-detail.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Project.objects.all().prefetch_related('areas__tasks')
```

and try show data `task` in template

Comment: my problem was on the template prefetch_related would help reducing query to the db ,thats all .